# Помощь в использовании VS для C

Tags: visual-studio

Как использовать sys/time.h Необходимо замерить время работа алгоритма. Выдает ошибку, может есть альтернатива?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- В `C` тоже можно использовать STL. В зависимости от того, что нужно измерить можно выбрать между [time](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time/) и [clock](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/). Простой пример:

```cpp
#include <time.h> //или #include <сtime>
...
clock_t t;
t = clock();
// что-то вычисляем
...
t = clock() - t;
float dt = (float)(clock() - t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

- В `C++` есть [chrono](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono)
- На Win доступна функция [GetTickCount](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-gettickcount) очень полезно когда надо измерить что-то поточнее. И есть [аналог на POSIX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7730134/6547185)